# Conditional loop: variable vs function?

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements

Is there any worthwhile reason to choose one over the other, for eg, performance or safety?

```
std::vector<std::string> some_vec{ "a","b","c"};

std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = some_vec.begin();
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator end = some_vec.end();

while( iter++ != end ){Do}
```

-

```
std::vector<std::string> some_vec{ "a","b","c"};

std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = some_vec.begin();

while( iter++ != some_vec.end() ){Do}
```

Comment: hm. `end = some_vec.begin()` is this a typo? Any reason not to use `for (auto&& iter : some_ver)` ?

Comment: Most compilers will probably optimize them to be the same.  You would have to profile your specific situation and see if one is faster than the other.

Comment: @LearnMore Even if to update the typo pointed to by Kamil Cuk nevertheless the both code snippets invoke undefined behavior when the vector is empty.:)

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, Typo. Edited!  Cant easily use auto as each loop will iter and process a pair of strings from the vec.

Comment: @LearnMore As for the question then for example the end iterator can be invalidated. So if the vector is changed inside the loop then the second code snippet is more safe.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow See code comment regarding empty vec. :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Noted! ...so no overhead from calling end() repeatedly as opposed to variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first relies on `end` not getting invalidated during the loop:

```
// some_vec initialised with data!
std::vector<std::string> some_vec; 

std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = some_vec.begin();
//std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator end = some_vec.end();

while( iter++ != some_vec.end() ){
    if (p(*iter)) iter = some_vec.insert(iter, "foo");
}
```

`insert` potentially invalidates all iterators, hence `end` cannot be used for the comparison.

For efficiency I would not worry too much. If `some_vec.end()` will always return the same iterator, I'd expect the compiler to be aware of this and perform appropriate optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `while( iter++ != end ){Do}` is wrong. You are eventually going to have end iterator in the loop body. Fixing that, we can use quick-bench.com to see if there's a performance difference:

```
#include <vector>

static void test0(benchmark::State& state)
{
    std::vector<std::string> some_vec{ "a", "b", "c" };

    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        auto iter = some_vec.cbegin();
        auto end = some_vec.cend();
        while (iter != end)
        {
            auto ch = (*iter++)[0];
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ch);
        }
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(some_vec);
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(test0);

static void test1(benchmark::State& state)
{
    // Code before the loop is not measured
    std::vector<std::string> some_vec{ "a", "b", "c" };
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        auto iter = some_vec.cbegin();
        while (iter != some_vec.cend())
        {
            auto ch = (*iter++)[0];
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ch);
        }
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(some_vec);
}
BENCHMARK(test1);
```

With no optimization and gcc 8.2, `test0` is 1.3 times faster:

### [image: No-optimization-results-gcc]

With optimization level `O3` `test0` is 1.1 times faster:

### [image: O3-gcc]

With Clang 7 they are about the same:

[image: O3-Clang]

So the performance seems to be a non-issue, but if the end interator can somehow be invalidated, the second version is safer.